# SQL - The first record only

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following segment of code in a stored procedure:

```
where
((Question = 'SurgicalSectionCompleted' and ChangeTo = 'True') or
(Question = 'MedicalSectionCompleted' and ChangeTo = 'True'))
```

However, sometimes in the table in question, there will be multiple entries where ChangeTo will be true. It is essential that I only calculate based on the FIRST record where ChangeTo is True. What SQL commands could I use to do this? Any ideas? Thanks.

The fields recorded in the table are: id, name, personNo, entryTime, question, changeFrom, ChangeTo

Comment: "First" as ordered by what?

Comment: By the date that they were created, e.g. Bob could have multiple rows where question was 'MedicalSectionCompleted' & ChangeTo was 'True'. But I only want to do the calculation on the very first row in which Bob done this.

Answer (score 10):

If you want only one row returned, then use `TOP 1`.  For the first, use `ORDER BY`:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
where Question in ('SurgicalSectionCompleted', 'MedicalSectionCompleted') and 
      ChangeTo = 'True'
order by entryTime asc;
```

If you want the first for each person, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personNo order by entryTime) as seqnum
      from t
      where Question in ('SurgicalSectionCompleted', 'MedicalSectionCompleted') and 
            ChangeTo = 'True'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `TOP 1`

```
select TOP 1 *
from table1
where
((Question = 'SurgicalSectionCompleted' and ChangeTo = 'True') or
(Question = 'MedicalSectionCompleted' and ChangeTo = 'True'))
order by <col1>
```